# issue with upgrading from itext5 to itext5.2

Tags: java, itext, etl

Recently we had to upgrade from itext version 5 to version 5.2 since the latter has support for Chinese languages. However one major change in the newer version is that it no longer supports the `TextProvidingRenderListener` class in the contsructor of `PdfTextExtractor` class. There was a class we had customized to utilize this feature :

```
public class CustomLocationAwarePdfRenderListener
implements TextProvidingRenderListener
{
    public CustomLocationAwarePdfRenderListener( int lineAlignErrorAllowed)
    {
        this.lineAlignErrorAllowed = lineAlignErrorAllowed;
        reset();
    }
```

However as an outcome there is now no way to use this class and the attribute called `lineAlignErrorAllowed` which was part of the constructor of the `CustomLocationAwarePdfRenderListener`. The `lineAlignErrorAllowed` basically acts as a parameter of scanning the minimum no. of lines before the source is considered as too complex. 
Any help on this topic would really be appreciated.

Comment: Text extracting is much better in iText 5.5.9 than in  iText 5.2, so why not migrate to 5.5.9 now that you've decided to upgrade anyway? Moreover: iText 5.2 had several issues. See the changelog: http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/changelogs/itext-520-521-february-29-2012-march-31-2012

Comment: Wow the author himself :) Thanks for your prompt response. I checked again with one of my teammates and he is facing the same problem when he tried with version 5.5.8 too. It would really be helpful if you could suggest some way to achieve the same thing i.e. passing the TextProvidingRenderListener object as a arguement in the contsructor of PdfTextExtractor class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to fix this issue after realizing that the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` class in the latest itext version is a worthy replacement for the `TextProvidingRenderListener`. Although this time we had to extend the class. The only other change that was needed is to alter to code to use the now static `PdfTextExtractor` class by passing an instance of the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` to the `getTextFromPage`. Had a bit of a struggle searching for the latest itext API reference doc, but got them [here](http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/classes) finally. (Somehow they show up with some different formatting than regular java API docs but one can live with that).

Comment: I am the QA Engineer at iText Software himself. :-) If you prefer regular Java API docs, you can also consult http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/. These are built by our CI from the development branch, so there may be a few tiny differences with the latest official release.

Comment: Thanks very much for this link, it was the thing I was expecting when I started googling for the apis. If it's not so much trouble I think you can provide it on this page too http://developers.itextpdf.com/apis. Bookmarked it now for posterity!